# List Append Conditionals

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

In this specific situation, How do I make a proper if conditional that appends only a price value for example below 53 to a list?

```
offers_list = re.findall("<div class=\"list\"(.*?)</div>", http_response_body, re.DOTALL) # Find list of offers in HTTP Response Body
price_list = []
offers_list2 = []

for i in offers_list:   # loop in the list of offers to look for the specific price values
    a = re.findall("\"price\"=(.*?)\"", i)  # Find specific price value within in each offer
    print a
    price_list.append(a) # Append to list only if the price is lower than X amount
    offers_list2.append(a)
```

The above code outputs:

```
[u'47.00']
[u'49.00']
[u'49.00']
[u'50.00']
[u'50.00']
[u'50.00']
[u'50.00']
[u'51.50']
[u'52.50']
[u'53.00']
[...]
```

However `print a` outside the `for loop` prints only one value obviously because it did only one search instead of a loop trough the all the offers.

Comment: Probably a job for Beautiful Soup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your regex works properly, something like this would probably do:

```
for price  in a:
    if int(price)<=53:
        price_list.append(price)
        offers_list2.append(price)
```

Also, [DO NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I think the asker wants `< 53` not `<= 53`

Comment: Prices should probably be float values, not int.

Comment: How safe is `float` for money amounts?  See PEP 327.